# ANCESTOR Query Parse Error: Using DISTINCT

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

Not [this question (where the problem is using `ANCESTOR =`  instead of `ANCESTOR IS`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463964/ancestor-query-parse-error)

I used `ANCESTOR IS` properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch_no 
FROM Entry 
WHERE ANCESTOR IS KEY('ag1kZXZ-dHRiLXRhbWVychkLEgdCcmV3ZXJ5IgxCUi1USEVSRURQRUEM')
```

But I still got an error:

> Identifier is a reserved keyword as symbol ANCESTOR

[image: a screenshot of Google interactive GQL console followed by the error "Identifier is a reserved keyword as symbol ANCESTOR"]

Why is that?

**EDIT**

I'm getting the same error later years later as I try to update from `db` to `ndb`, but I think it's a different reason...

> Identifier is a reserved keyword at symbol ANCESTOR

But in this case my query is not using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT *
FROM Balance
WHERE ANCESTOR IS KEY('...')
AND first_balance_ever = TRUE
ORDER BY created_date
```

So I'm not sure the problem here, maybe it's `ANCESTOR` related, maybe it's `KEY(...)` related...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `DISTINCT` was causing the problem. Remove it and the query works as expected.

I think the query is implicitly projecting only that property you `DISTINCT` on, so you cannot access the key/ancestor for `ANCESTOR IS`. (But is this true **even if you use `SELECT *`?**)

But the error message is not very clear...

Google describes that `DISTINCT` is experimental. Mentions  this in [`db.Query`](https://web.archive.org/web/20140702132134/https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries) documentation:

> #### Grouping<sup>(experimental)</sup>
>
> Projection queries can use the `distinct` keyword to ensure that only completely unique results will be returned in a result set. This will only return the first result for entities **which have the same values for the properties that are being projected.**

And in the [GQL documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140702131638/https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference)

> The optional `DISTINCT`<sup>(experimental)</sup> clause specifies that only completely unique results will be returned in a result set. This will only return **the first result for entities which have the same values for the properties that are being projected.**

Answer (score 0):

I modified my question because I faced this error years later when updating from `db` to `ndb`.

**If only going from `db` to `ndb`**
My problem was a GQL Query like this

```
"ANCESTOR IS KEY('{}')".format(model.key)
```

Notice the difference was going

- from this: `model.key()`, which returned a "url safe" encodable string value...
- to [`model.key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb), which stringifies as KEY('Kind', 'id')

The result was a this string, which is clearly wrong:

```
ANCESTOR IS KEY('KEY('Kind', 'id')')
```

**If going from `db` or `ndb` to the Datastore**

I think the problem is [described here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/PobiAvn8NEE/m/ZeKWjpwTDgAJ), and [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#unsupported_features_and_behavior_differences_from_mysqlpython_gql)

> Python GQL expression `ANCESTOR IS <entity-or-key-value>` is represented in Datastore GQL as the more general expression `__key__ HAS ANCESTOR <key-value>`

So I think `db` is using Python GQL, whereas `ndb` might be using Datastore GQL.

Note also:

> Python GQL supports queries using a URL-safe (base64-encoded) key. **Datastore GQL does not.**

...although note that `ndb` does have this method...

```
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=encoded_key)
```

The ["DB to NDB Client Library Migration" documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb) doesn't make it clear how GQL changes... although does imply `ndb` keys are different than `db` keys:

> You can even convert between `ext.db` and `NDB` keys using `ndb.Key.from_old_key()` and `key.to_old_key()`.

[The **legacy** GQL reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference) says the Key can be:

> an [entity key literal](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/datastore/keyclass#Key), with either a string-encoded key or a [complete path of kinds and key names/IDs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/datastore/entities):
>
> - `KEY('encoded key')`
> - `KEY('kind', 'name'/ID [, 'kind', 'name'/ID...])`

But the [Datastore GQL reference says](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference)