# Are GQL DISTINCT ancestor queries not supported?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gql

This works:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
query = ndb.gql("SELECT distinct id from Pocket")
query.fetch()
```

This also works:

```
query = ndb.gql("SELECT id from Pocket where ancestor is :1")
query = query.bind(u.key)
```

This raises an error:

```
query = ndb.gql("SELECT distinct id from Pocket where ancestor is :1")
query = query.bind(u.key)
```

The error is:

```
BadQueryError: Parse Error: Identifier is a reserved keyword at symbol ancestor
```

Are GQL DISTINCT ancestor queries not supported on NDB for python, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be intended behavior. Based off the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225368/ancestor-query-parse-error-using-distinct), the issue is coming from using distinct with projection queries. As it’s only meant to be used with properties and not ancestors, [as seen here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax):

> The optional DISTINCT(experimental) clause specifies that only completely unique results will be returned in a result set. This will only return the first result for entities which have the same values for the properties that are being projected.

Comment: Where is the link to the stackoverflow article?

Comment: I see what you mean now... The `__key__` field is not returned when you DISTINCT, and without a `__key__`, ANCESTOR IS makes no sense to the API. Well, either way, the error message doesn't help at all.